# Speak, ask questions in between

Tags: word-usage, phrases

Two people are talking, so a third person comes and cuts in, so the two people say:

You shouldn't speak in between.

And a kid asks questions in the middle of a lecture, the teacher says:

Don't ask questions in between.

Is the use of "in between" natural? If not hen what would you use?

Answer (score 2):

No, "in between" is not idiomatic in that context.

In the first example, a more natural sentence might be: "You shouldn't **interrupt**."

In the second scenario, the teacher might say "Don't ask questions **until after** the lecture." (Though the phrasing "Don't ask..." seems rude to me. I would expect something more along the lines of "Please hold all questions...")

Comment: So here, in the second sentence, can't it be: Don't speak in the middle of the lecture.

Comment: Yes, that would be fine.

Comment: I would go with more civilized approach such as "You shouldn't jump into other's conversation." and for the second sentence "Please keep your questions until after the lecture." but Heck! What do I know...